# redux normalized state: byId and allIds pattern

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am going through the documented pattern for structuring application state:

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

There one sees the following suggested way of maintaining the posts of a hypothetical blogging application:

```
 posts : {
    byId : {
        "post1" : {
            id : "post1",
            author : "user1",
            body : "......",
            comments : ["comment1", "comment2"]
        },
        "post2" : {
            id : "post2",
            author : "user2",
            body : "......",
            comments : ["comment3", "comment4", "comment5"]
        }
    },
    allIds : ["post1", "post2"]
}
```

It is not at all clear to me what is the benefit of maintaining the `allIds` field on that state. Doesn't the following data structure contain the exact same information?:

```
posts : {
        "post1" : {
            id : "post1",
            author : "user1",
            body : "......",
            comments : ["comment1", "comment2"]
        },
        "post2" : {
            id : "post2",
            author : "user2",
            body : "......",
            comments : ["comment3", "comment4", "comment5"]
        }
}
```

The way I see it, the first approach (i.e. the officially suggested one) has redundant information which is normally seen as a defect. The only benefit of the first approach that I see is in case we are using the `byId` property to cache some posts in advance. I am sure the official redux documentation has valid reasons for suggesting this pattern. I have used Redux in a few React apps but nothing too complex so I must be clearly failing to see something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `allIds` field has a couple benefits:

- It provides a consistent array reference for "all IDs", whereas something like `Object.keys(state.posts)` creates a new array every time
- It can act as a default sort order for all the items, whether it be based on insertion order or something else.

[Our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) now has a new [`createEntityAdapter` API](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter) that implements the logic for managing this kind of normalized state shape, which it organizes as `{ids: [], entities: {} }`.  It specifically implements the ability to keep the `ids` array in sorted order, and ensures the `ids` array only changes when items are added, removed, or the sort order changes.

You might also want to read through [Advanced Redux Entity Normalization](https://medium.com/@dcousineau/advanced-redux-entity-normalization-f5f1fe2aefc5), which has further thoughts on the use of ID arrays to indicate filtering and sort order.